# how to extract the text from a Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement object

Tags: powershell, iis-7

If I run the command in powershell:

```
C:\Get-Website
```

it outputs

```
Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
Default Web Site 1               %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot  http *:80:
                                                                net.tcp 808:*
                                                                net.pipe *
                                                                net.msmq localhost
                                                                msmq.formatname 
                                                                localhost
```

But if I try to select just the Bindings:

```
C:\Get-Website | where {$_.Name -eq "Default Web Site"} | select Bindings
```

It returns:

```
bindings : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement
```

How do I extract the contents of this object into a useful format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bindings property is a collection so you have to use the `ExpandProperty` parameter:

```
Get-Website -Name "Default Web Site" | select -ExpandProperty Bindings
```

To drill down further:

```
get-website -name "Default Web Site" | select -ExpandProperty Bindings | Select -ExpandProperty Collection
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I was working on similar command but for list all Sites and its bindings. In IIS  this is what i did :

```
get-childItem | 
select * , @{Name="SiteBindings"; Expression = {($_.Bindings.Collection | %{$_.protocol + "  " + $_.BindingInformation} | Out-String).replace("`r","" ) }}
```

Note the replace("`r","" ). It is needed if you need to export to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the `Get-WebBinding` cmdlet that can be used if you don't want to start from `Get-Website`.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

Get-WebBinding
```

This will display all of the binding info for all websites, and you can filter it down further from there.

Here's sample output of running the above command.

```
protocol             : http
bindingInformation   : *:80:
sslFlags             : 0
isDsMapperEnabled    : False
certificateHash      :
certificateStoreName :
ItemXPath            : /system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site' and @id='1']
RunspaceId           : b7052f71-a213-437c-a97f-00fb9fa84a7f
Attributes           : {Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute,
                       Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute,
                       Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute,
                       Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute…}
ChildElements        : {}
ElementTagName       : binding
Methods              : {Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationMethod,
                       Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationMethod,
                       Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationMethod,
                       Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationMethod…}
Schema               : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema
```